# Project in multi project can't find specific project dependency

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have a Multi Project wich has the following structure:

- core
- pluginApi
- plugins/globalOptions
- plugins/commandPlugin

Where "plugins" is just a directory.

Now I have a couple classes inside "globalOptions":

- at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint.OptionExtension
- at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint.OptionHandlerExtension

And one class inside "commandPlugin":

- at.lyze.plugin.commandPlugin.CommandPluginTest

The "CommandPluginTest" class uses"OptionExtension" and "OptionHandlerExtension" from the other project:

```
import at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint.OptionExtension;
import at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint.OptionHandlerExtension;

List<OptionHandlerExtension> optionHandlers = wrapper.getPluginManager().getExtensions(OptionHandlerExtension.class);
        for (OptionHandlerExtension optionHandler : optionHandlers) {
            logger.warn(optionHandler.getOption(getClass(), "TestOption"));
        }
```

---

My gradle build files look like:

"globalOptions":

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':pluginApi')
}
```

"commandPlugin":

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':plugins/globalOptions')
    compile project(':pluginApi')
}
```

---

When trying to run the "jar" task on every project I get the following error:

```
Note: Extension found in at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.GlobalOptions$TestExtension
:plugins/globalOptions:compileJava
:plugins/globalOptions:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:plugins/globalOptions:classes
:plugins/globalOptions:jar
Note: Extension found in at.lyze.plugin.commandPlugin.CommandPluginTest$BlarghExtension
    C:\Users\wml\Desktop\LocalRepos\darkowlbot\plugins\commandPlugin\src\main\java\at\lyze\plugin\commandPlugin\Co    mmandPluginTest.java:3: error: package at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint does not exist
import at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint.OptionExtension;
                                                  ^
C:\Users\wml\Desktop\LocalRepos\darkowlbot\plugins\commandPlugin\src\main\java\at\lyze\plugin\commandPlugin\Co    mmandPluginTest.java:4: error: package at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint does not exist
import at.lyze.plugin.globalOptions.extensionpoint.OptionHandlerExtension;
                                              ^
C:\Users\wml\Desktop\LocalRepos\darkowlbot\plugins\commandPlugin\src\main\java\at\lyze\plugin\commandPlugin\Co    mmandPluginTest.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    public static class BlarghExtension implements EventProcessorExtension, OptionExtension {
                                                                            ^
  symbol:   class OptionExtension
  location: class CommandPluginTest
C:\Users\wml\Desktop\LocalRepos\darkowlbot\plugins\commandPlugin\src\main\java\at\lyze\plugin\commandPlugin\CommandPluginTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        public void initializeOptions(OptionHandlerExtension optionHandlerExtension) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class OptionHandlerExtension
  location: class CommandPluginExtensionClass
4 errors
:plugins/commandPlugin:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

---

Have I done something wrong here or why does this fail?
I can provide additional information if needed.

Running gradle 2.9

Edit:

Settings.gradle (Global project with every include)

```
rootProject.name = 'DarkOwlBot'
include 'pluginApi'
include 'core'
include 'plugins/globalOptions'
include 'plugins/commandPlugin'
include 'plugins/guiFeederService'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @ReneGroeschke said, you should leave out the `into ('classes')` line [here](http://bitbucket.lyze.at/projects/DAR/repos/darkowlbot/browse/plugins/globalOptions/build.gradle#10). You're altering the structure of the produced artifact.

Comment: Ah thank you!

Basically I'm using a library which requires the directory structure which is obviously wrong for gradle hence it can't "jar task" the other projects.

Comment: You could produce two artifacts, 1 zip and 1 jar with the structures as required for your library and general java consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, gradle has problems with the '/' in project names. By default the project name is also used to create the jar for the project. This likely results in wrong file paths.

I think your best options to solve this are:

1. Change the include statements in your settings.gradle file to be
   `include ':plugins:globalOptions'` and reference globalOptions by 
   `compile project(':plugins:globalOptions')`
2. Change the include statement in your settings.gradle file to be
   `include ':globalOptions'` and configure the project directory explicit via `project(':globalOptions').projectDir = file('plugins/globalOptions')` 
   and reference it in your dependency block via `compile project(':globalOptions')`

Comment: Hmm nope. Doesn't work.

I've changed inside the settings.gradle every include to 'plugins:<name>' and inside the "commandPlugin" project the depdendependency to `compile project(':plugins:globalOptions')`

Comment: Thanks for helping. However it still doesn't work. settings.gradle: `include :globalOptions` and lower then: `project(':globalOptions').projectDir = file('plugins/globalOptions')`   Wherever "commandPlugin" build file looks like `compile project(':globalOptions')`` ... Getting the same package doesn't exist error

Comment: Ah sorry for not clarifying ... That also doesn't work.
I'm currently cleaning my repository so that there aren't any passwords and I can give you the link to it if you want to have a look at it on your own

Comment: Ah I hope that's allowed ... [but here you go](http://bitbucket.lyze.at/projects/DAR/repos/darkowlbot/browse). Make sure to change to the "dev" branch … although … it doesn't matter...